# Mouse buttons and keyboard become unresponsive after varying idle times

Tags: xfce

At certain times my display semi-freezes. Symptoms are as follows:

- The mouse moves but no button presses are registered
- If the mouse is moved over the task bar, the windows are not highlighted
- Programs that are running continue to run as normal
  <sub>For example, the clock continues running; while I was on TeamSpeak, sound continued working, push-to-talk continued working and the text chat updates showed up</sub>
- Keyboard inputs will mostly not register; e.g. I cannot switch between windows using Alt-Tab
- However, switching to `tty1` through `tty6` via keyboard shortcuts (Alt+Ctrl+F1 through F6) works and I can debug and crude-fix the problem on console. I can also switch back to `tty7` but there is no change in appearance if I did not apply a fix over in a console.

This semi-freeze seems to occur only when I am not doing anything. I have played extensive solitaire sessions and I have surfed the internet for extended time without it happening, but five minutes of looking at open programs (not moving the mouse) were enough to make it happen *in some cases*.

One way to fix the issue is to restart the X server using `sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service`.
Killing or restarting the XFCE panel (e.g. `pidof xfce4-panel` follwed by `kill PID`) did not work; I was not able to restart the panel from inside the X server.
I had found multiple sources suggesting that this issue may be related to Nvidia drivers. However, it turns out that switching from `Nouveau` to the proprietary legacy Nvidia drivers just stops the monitor from receiving signals from the X server altogether. (`tty1` through `tty6` still worked, which is how I recovered from the driver installation.) It seems that there are some packages that the proprietary drivers depend on which ‘will not be installed’ (or something along those lines according to the package managers).

What might cause this and how might I be able to fix this permanently?

---

I am happy to provide any further information about my system or any required logfiles to help solve this issue; please ask in the comments. For now, here is the output of `neofetch`:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 5.4.0-72-generic 
Uptime: 4 hours, 37 mins 
Packages: 3557 (dpkg), 7 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1024x768 
DE: Xfce 
WM: Xfwm4 
WM Theme: Greybird 
Theme: Greybird [GTK2/3] 
Icons: elementary-xfce-dark [GTK2], elementary-xfce-darker [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: AMD FX-4300 (4) @ 3.800GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 
Memory: 1385MiB / 15996MiB`
```

---

Side note: I cannot say when this problem first started appearing. I had been living abroad since 2017 and instead of taking my whole desktop I simply took my harddisk and inserted it into a cheap desktop rig overseas. In February, I moved back to my home country and began using my rig from before again; but due to the complications around moving I had not used it much since returning and cannot say if this problem had existed since before my return or if it is a relatively new development.